# using unittest++ in Codelite

Tags: codelite, unittest++

After a lot of research:
I cannot actually appear to get unittest++ to work in Codelite.
Either on a Mac or Windows machine.
creating a project as a unittest++ project seems to go OK (as per Eran's suggestions).
Compiler recognises the libraries for unittest++ (or so it seems) but build always fails.
Attempting to run the project as a unittest++ project - NOTHING ever happens.

Obviously I am missing something here - no idea whether the issue is in the setup of unitttest and Codelite, making a unittest++ project, or something else??

Please, I am not a powerhouse programmer with decades of experience.
No assumptions should be made about my ability to follow general directions - I think exact instructions will be required.
I have already spent about a week getting a version of Codelite to run properly on both my Mac and my Windows machine - so be gentle.

Tony Jay

Comment: Just came across this.  You seem to have successfully built the UnitTest++ judging by the statement "Compiler recognises the libraries" is this correct?